# Term for movements in a song?

Tags: movements

In Skyrim's Score, Combat 6 there are several "movements":

0:17~

0:33~

0:48~

1:04~

1:36~

2:07~2:24

Here is the song:

I do not inherently believe that the term movements applies to parts of a song though I could be wrong, if not what is the term for the various sequences I've listed above?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the term you are looking for here is a **passage**:

> A passage is a musical idea that may or may not be complete or independent. For example, fill, riff, and all sections.

Those definitely aren't different movements in that piece. A movement is a:

> self-contained part of a musical composition or musical form.

Those sections (or passages) you are referring to aren't self contained, they are also not independent. In a piece movements typically have a pause in between, before starting in a different key and/or tempo.

Comment: Good suggestion, passage. In this particular case I would consider the alternative "theme", as the piece is probably a kind of rhapsody compressing the game's soundtrack, normally several hours lengthy, into just a few minutes. Each section succinctly presents a theme that is fully extended and developed in the proper full soundtrack.

Comment: @joseem That's a good point! I hadn't considered it being a rhapsody.